# Is there a way to compare two ciphertexts generated by AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

Is there a way to compare ciphertexts in AWS KMS, so imply that matching values gives matching plain texts ? Because AWS KMS spits different ciphertexts each time.

Comment: Probably not. In general, cryptographic schemes are designed to prevent that sort of thing.

Comment: `AWS KMS spits different ciphertexts each time` this is one of required properties for security. So answer is no, you should have no means to match the encrypted values (without decrypting first)

Comment: Thanks guys, please add an answer and i can close the same.